# c++ float to const wchar_t* converting function

Tags: c++

I'm converting a float to a const wchar_t *

```
DisplayText(ConversionUtils::FloatToWstring(fps).c_str()); // Prints garbage

DisplayText(std::to_wstring(fps).c_str()); // Doesn't print anything to the device.
```

with this function :

```
std::wstring ConversionUtils::FloatToWstring(float value) {

    return std::to_wstring(value);
}
```

I want to get something like that :

```
DisplayText(ConversionUtils::FloatToConstWcharPtr(fps));
```

Comment: Why do you need to return a pointer? return directly the value.

Comment: I'm really curious why you use `std::to_string` to lexcast to `std::string`, then convert the result into a `std::wstring`. Why don't you just write `std::to_wstring` instead of that entire function? Then you also wouldn't need the excess dynamic allocation that you've put in place for no apparent reason.

Comment: Also your function names don't match.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit updated the code, but still to_wstring doesn't give me a const wchar_t* and it's still displaying garbage after the c_str(). If I inline to_wstring(myFloat).c_str() it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Alex: You're saying things but where is your [MCVE]? We cannot fix the real mistake that you made without seeing the code that contains the mistake. I can tell you that `std::to_wstring` doesn't contain a mistake, so you are focusing on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return by value:

```
std::wstring ConversionUtils::FloatToWchar(float value) {
    std::string str = std::to_string(value);
    return std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Or better, use `std::to_wstring()` instead.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work, it's displaying empty squares instead of numbers. I did as you said and than called c_str() on the return value to get the const wchar_t*.

Comment: This whole function is completely pointless. `FloatToWchar` should be `std::to_wstring`; end of story.

Comment: Nope, it's still not an MCVE. What is `DisplayText`? Y'know, the actual function that currently isn't working.